# Do misaligned or missing teeth affect singing negatively?

Tags: voice, performing

This is not about a situation where the condition of the teeth cause physical discomfort to the individual nor is it a situation where they are wearing braces or retainers.

Do misaligned or missing teeth affect singing negatively?

Comment: I don't think getting wisdom teeth pulled affects your singing, so clearly there's a limit as to which teeth affect singing negatively once lost. However, lacking incisors will affect your ability to say certain consonant sounds (such as "s" and "th").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only as far as the front teeth - top in particular - will cause some sibilant type sounds to come out strangely, but I guess that when that problem is worked on enough, it can be overcome.

Answer (score 1):

Singing is less definitely affected than reed instrument playing.  Try finding a photograph of Freddy Mercury showing his teeth [such as this.](https://queenphotos.files.wordpress.com/2013/09/freddie-mercury-magic-tour-1986.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

On my top row of teeth, my lateral incisors: (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Teeth_diagram.png)

are higher than they should be. Additionally, I have quite a large overbite.

I sang small vocal jazz ensemble in high school and in college and these issues have never negatively affected me in any way that I have noticed. Incidentally, I also played baritone saxophone in high school and in college, and never noticed a problem there, either.